# how to use SAPUI5 library css in window.print?

Tags: css, printing, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have developed the SAPUI5 application which is having a print option.
When I click on print button, I am writing print area content into document and giving print by using window.print();

```
 var printContents = document.getElementById("printArea").innerHTML;
 var win = window.open("", "PrintWindow");
 win.document.write("<div class='page'>" + printContents + "</div>");
      setTimeout(function() {
       win.print();
       win.stop();
      }, 2000);
```

But the issue is I am missing SAPUI5 default library CSS in my print.
I need SAPUI5 default style sheet in my print,how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came across same problem.
Please add below code between "var win..." and "win.document.write...".

```
$.each(document.styleSheets, function(index, oStyleSheet) {
  if(oStyleSheet.href){
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = oStyleSheet.type;
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = oStyleSheet.href;
    //win.document.head.appendChild(link); --> this doesn't work in IE
    win.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = win.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML + link.outerHTML;
  }
});
```

Comment: I implemented this solution but I receive error "document.createElement is not a constructor". The explicit css link in the opened print window is webidetestingxxxxx.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/com/css/style.css which is not a valid link to the css. Any idea how to resolve?